# ASP.NET menu control

Tags: asp.net, menu

I want to expand my menu names to the end of blue border, like on pict.
http://img.villagephotos.com/p/2005-10/1086302/menu.JPG , what should I do in css ? i try with positioning and width.

```
CSS
div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display:table;

    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
}

< asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu"  Font-Bold="true" runat="server" CssClass="menu"
     EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false"  Orientation="Horizontal">
    < Items>
       < asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>    
       < asp:MenuItem Text="Projects" Value="Projects" 
            NavigateUrl="~/Projects.aspx">    
            < asp:MenuItem Text="SEED" Value="SEED" NavigateUrl="~/Seed.aspx">
            </asp:MenuItem>    
            < asp:MenuItem Text="SEMS" Value="SEMS" NavigateUrl="~/SEMS.aspx">
            </asp:MenuItem>
            < asp:MenuItem Text="IPR" Value="IPR" NavigateUrl="~/IPR.aspx">
            </asp:MenuItem>    
            < asp:MenuItem Text="Beneficiaries" Value="Beneficiaries" 
                   NavigateUrl="~/Beneficiaries.aspx">
            </asp:MenuItem>
            < asp:MenuItem Text="About Us" Value="About US" 
                   NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>    
            < asp:MenuItem Text="Contacts" Value="Contacts" 
                   NavigateUrl="~/Contacts.aspx">
            </asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
   </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: how will I expand menu items names ? (home,projects..)

Comment: @lari Vocal: I haven't got what you mean by "Expanding Menu Items Names" !!

Comment: loook at picture, selected area is what I see when i click on "projects" , but this blue border is with firebug, and i want selected area to be same as border.

Comment: http://img.villagephotos.com/p/2005-10/1086302/meni.JPG, , see now , what is problem ?

Answer (score 0):

What I would advise is using set widths for the `<li>` tags and the `<div>` that has the list menu in.

ASP.NET will give your `<li>` elements a generated ID so make classes like `.home` and `.projects` and apply them to the `<asp:MenuItem cssClass="">` attribute

Comment: <li> i think can not be nested in items menu.